# How to build a windows phone 8 application like kid's corner?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need help on how to build an app for windows 8 phone which is exactly similar to Kid's Corner application which is available with NOKIA LUMIA 520.

I registered with the App Studio of Microsoft and tried to create a simple application like album but as a nubee I am not aware of all fundamentals and so need a simple guide.

Here is what I want my application should do:

1. Once you launch it, you can not go back until you lock phone and unlock it using password. same way as Kid's Corner.
2. I want that the app user should be able to see videos and photos only which the app is allowed to access.
3. User should be able to Zoom photos and play pause videos and using touch-slide can view the next one.
4. User should not be able to delete any files.

Thanks for pointing me to the exact resource where I can find some things which are easy to understand and simple to do :) .

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

Is it possible to get the source code of Kid's Zone/Corner application?

Answer (score 6):

*1. Once you launch it, you can not go back until you lock phone and unlock it using password. same way as Kid's Corner.*

**This is impossible to lock user into your app.** User always can exit or suspend your app using hardware buttons, you just can handle back button tab, but user also can touch to startmenu button or can hold to backbutton.

And you cant get kid zone's source code, its part of Windows Phone OS.

Comment: When Kid's corner is launched there is no way to go back to main section. This is already there. But my basic question is can I build something exactly similar to Kid's Corner and customize it as per my needs?

Comment: He already answered your question. The answer is no. The reason kids corner can do it is because it comes with the phone. It's made with Microsofts secret sauce. Go work for Microsoft and maybe they will tell you how they did it.

Comment: So it means I will have to accept NO as the answer? So bad for me. No hacker around???? I will wait for some days before accepting "NO" as the answer. :( Anyways, thank you guys!